# JQuery Append removing characters in IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JQuery, when I loop through an array and append the values to a UL it works fine in Chrome and Firefox. In IE and Edge it truncates the value if it starts with a number followed by a dash or underscore.

```js
var listItems = $('#list1');

var result = ['1-2-3', '1_2_3', 'a-b-c', 'a_b_c'];

$.each(result, function(key, value) {
  listItems.append($('<li/>', {
    value: value,
    text: value
  }))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1"></ul>
```

Expected Result:

```
<ul>
<li value="1-2-3">1-2-3</li>
<li value="1_2_3">1_2_3</li>
<li value="a-b-c">a-b-c</li>
<li value="a_b_c">a_b_c</li>
</ul>
```

Actual Result:

```
<ul>
<li value="1">1-2-3</li>
<li value="1">1_2_3</li>
<li value="a-b-c">a-b-c</li>
<li value="a_b_c">a_b_c</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `value`. According to the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element), the value of an `li` element must be an integer:

> The `value` attribute, if present, must be a valid integer. It is used to determine the ordinal value of the list item, when the `li`'s list owner is an `ol` element.

IE and Edge are enforcing this requirement by extracting the integer prefix from the values; they only leave the value alone if it doesn't begin with an integer.

If you need to attach custom data to an element, use `data-XXX` attributes, which can be set in jQuery with the `data:` property when creating the element, and you can fetch and update with the `.data()` method.

```js
var listItems = $('#list1');

var result = ['1-2-3', '1_2_3', 'a-b-c', 'a_b_c'];

$.each(result, function(key, value) {
  listItems.append($('<li/>', {
    data: {
      value: value
    },
    text: value
  }))
});

$("li").click(function() {
  alert($(this).data("value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1"></ul>
```

Comment: We both learned something from this, I didn't know about this special use of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As an FYI, I wound up adding a data-value attribute to the LI instead of using jQuery.data()

```
$.each(result, function (key, value) {
    listItems.append($('<li/>', {
      text: value
    }).attr("data-value", value))
  }
);
```

Thsnks again for your help!